# How to navigate to a new page in Gambas3

Tags: user-interface, gambas

I find myself having to deal with some *delightful* legacy software written in Gambas3. I have to extend the functionality of a small GUI application with a new control page.

Naturally, as for similar GUI libraries I've worked with (web, Android development, flutter, ...) I came looking for a way to navigate between different pages. It is almost implied as possible by the organization in `.form` files.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to achieve this. Given multiple different `Form` objects, how can I swap the currently viewed window between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the uses of the Gambas ONE forum I now have [the answer](https://forum.gambas.one/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=769&p=1994&hilit=maldus#p1994).

To achieve a "form switch" one must hide/close the first form and show the next:

```
Public Sub Next_Click()

  FSecond.Show
  Me.Hide

End

Public Sub Return_Click()

  FMain.Show
  Me.Hide

End
```

Hiding the form will just make it disappear from view, closing it will destroy it (and following calls to `Show` will create it again).